# Working copy NEVER ready to Merge

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm working with S.V.N, Tortoise, VisualStudio, dot.net framework 4.0 and C#. I want to merge a branch to a trunk... well lets be honest, I just want to merge something, anything ! Because I'm testing SVN so we can actually use it for our next project without stepping on each other's feet. I already know how to take care of conflicts. But I also need to know how to merge back a branch. But anyhow I commit everything and resolve all conflicts, there still are some conditions required before even pushing the merge button :

1. No uncommitted modifications
2. Working copy at a single revision
3. No switched children
4. Complete Working copy

For whats about condition 3 and 4, everything is ok, even thought i don't understand how could i create such situations. But condition 1 and 2 are not ok. What for ? The project do not contains any conflict and as been committed correctly... what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finaly found something, in the previous window, just before the 4 conditions pop-up and prevent any merge, there is an option at the very botton of that previous window, a checkbox that propose this :

```
Perform pre-merge best practices check
```

I remove the check of that checkbox. No more conditions for merging ! I don't know if it's a good thing, but it merged correctly... this time.

Answer (score 1):

> But condition 1 and 2 are not ok. What for ?

Reintegrate merge (in comapre to sync merge) has more requirements to destination (working copy) state. I belive, that having local modifications and mixed revisions can lead to incorrect merge due to nature of reintegrate merge. I not sure if this *can* be solved with more development efforts of Subversion dev team, but current implementation require desribed state.

> Working copy NEVER ready to Merge

It is simple to fix. Either commit local changes:

```
cd <path to working copy root>
svn commit -m "Unsaved work"
svn up
```

or revert them

```
cd <path to working copy root>
svn revert . -R
svn up
```

then your wc ready for reintegrate merge.

---

P.S. Actually, I belive it is always better perfrom merge (sync or reintegrate) into working copy with described state. For this I keep separate, always clean working copy, which I use only for merges.

Comment: I'm working with Tortoise integrated to Windows, in order to explain this the simplest way to my partners, i need this to be ( command line free ). All i need to merge is rigth click on my project, anyway my project was correctly commited so this is not the solution i was searching for, even thought it iseems useful i admit.